# Copy one datatable into another

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have 1st datatable as:

dtOld

Columns:

C  E

second datatable as:

dtNew:

A  B  C  D E  F

I just wanted to copy stOld data into dtNew with specified columns.

i.e.:

C col's value of dtOld should copy in D col value of dtNew..and  E
 Col to F col

I tried some complex logic, but it does not worked.

Is there any way to solve this.

I tried as:

```
DataTable dtOld = new DataTable();
                        dtOld = ds.Tables[0];
                        string[] columns = { "c", "E" };
                        string[] columns2 = { "D", "F " };
                        foreach (DataRow sourcerow in dtOld.Rows)
                        {
                            DataRow destRow = dtNew.NewRow();
                            int cntm = 0;
                            foreach (string colname in columns)
                            {
                                destRow[columns2[cntm]] = sourcerow[colname];
                                cntm++; 
                            }
                            dtNew.Rows.Add(destRow);
                        }
```

Please help me.

Comment: Does this give you an error? If so, which line gives you the error? If not, then what result do you actually get from this? Have you debugged the code to ensure that the `dtOld` is being filled correctly from the `ds` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a simple copy from a fixed set of columns to another set, so why to complicate things?

```
foreach (DataRow sourcerow in dtOld.Rows)
{
    DataRow destRow = dtNew.NewRow();
    destRow["D"] = sourcerow["c"];
    destRow["F"] = sourcerow["E"];
    dtNew.Rows.Add(destRow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach (DataRow row in dtOld.Rows)
        dtNew.LoadDataRow(new[]
                                  {
                                      null, // default value
                                      null,
                                      null,
                                      row["C"],
                                      null,
                                      row["E"]
                                  }, LoadOption.Upsert);
```